# php decode JSON -> mysql query

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to make query.
I don't know why this php doesn't work.

there is no change in my DB.

are there errors?

```
<?

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);


$con = mysql_connect("localhost:(port)","ID","PW") 
   or die('Cannot connect to the DB');

mysql_select_db("DBID",$con);

$row = $obj->{"menusel_row"};
$col = $obj->{"menusel_col"};
$val = $obj->{"menuvalue"};

mysql_query("UPDATE recommend SET $row = '$val' where id = '$col'", $con);


mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: What does `print "UPDATE recommend SET $row = '$val' where id = '$col'" output?

Comment: no output no change.
can I check logs?

Comment: 'menusel_row' is String, the others are integer numbers

Comment: Please do some debugging. `var_dump()` all relevant variables, values and function returns. Explicitly check for MySQL errors. We have no information to go on here.

Comment: What kind of error. don't say _Why this php doesn't work_ without show us what kind of error. Its liable to close. Include at the beginning of your file: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and check for possible error in it.

Answer (score 2):

A brief note: you are using short open tags for PHP `<?`, this feature most probably is disabled on your PHP server, because it is obsolete.

Absence of any output most probably is related to that. Use `<?php` instead.